# How to find a pair of numbers in a list given a specific range?

Tags: math, search, range

The problem is as such:

given an array of ***N*** numbers, find two numbers in the array such that they will have a range(max - min) value of ***K***.

for example:

input:

```
5 3
25 9 1 6 8
```

output:

```
9 6
```

So far, what i've tried is first sorting the array and then finding two complementary numbers using a nested loop. However, because this is a sort of brute force method, I don't think it is as efficient as other possible ways.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt(), k = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int count = 0;
        int a, b;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                if(Math.max(arr[i], arr[j]) - Math.min(arr[i], arr[j]) == k) {
                    a = arr[i];
                    b = arr[j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    }
}
```

Much appreciated if the solution was in code (any language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code in Python 3 that solves your problem. This should be easy to understand, even if you do not know Python.

This routine uses your idea of sorting the array, but I use two variables `left` and `right` (which define two places in the array) where each makes just one pass through the array. So other than the sort, the time efficiency of my code is `O(N)`. The sort makes the entire routine `O(N log N)`. This is better than your code, which is `O(N^2)`.

I never use the inputted value of `N`, since Python can easily handle the actual size of the array. I add a sentinel value to the end of the array to make the inner short loops simpler and quicker. This involves another pass through the array to calculate the sentinel value, but this adds little to the running time. It is possible to reduce the number of array accesses, at the cost of a few more lines of code--I'll leave that to you. I added input prompts to aid my testing--you can remove those to make my results closer to what you seem to want. My code prints the larger of the two numbers first, then the smaller, which matches your sample output. But you may have wanted the order of the two numbers to match the order in the original, un-sorted array--if that is the case, I'll let you handle that as well (I see multiple ways to do that).

```
# Get input
N, K = [int(s) for s in input('Input N and K: ').split()]
arr = [int(s) for s in input('Input the array: ').split()]

arr.sort()
sentinel = max(arr) + K + 2
arr.append(sentinel)
left = right = 0
while arr[right] < sentinel:
    # Move the right index until the difference is too large
    while arr[right] - arr[left] < K:
        right += 1
    # Move the left index until the difference is too small
    while arr[right] - arr[left] > K:
        left += 1
    # Check if we are done
    if arr[right] - arr[left] == K:
        print(arr[right], arr[left])
        break
```